# Export the result of stored procedure into text file as my computer work as both client/server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure which takes as argument the function name and then finds out the full body of that function and stores it in a local variable `V_FullString`.

I need this output not to show in screen rather to put it in text file.

Is it possible ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_DictionaryFunction] 
    @P_FunctionName VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @V_ObjectName varchar(100) = @P_FunctionName;
    DECLARE @V_FULLSTRING VARCHAR(5000) = ''

    IF EXISTS (SELECT object_id FROM SYS.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@V_ObjectName))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @V_TABLE TABLE (Line VARCHAR(500))

        INSERT INTO @V_TABLE 
            EXECUTE SP_HELPTEXT @V_ObjectName

        SELECT @V_FULLSTRING = @V_FULLSTRING + Line 
        FROM @V_TABLE

        PRINT @V_FULLSTRING
    END
END
```

Comment: Is this a one-time export?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: The biggest problem here is probably the `print`; many tools ignore `print` (or: ignore it by default, with an option to enable them). If you use `select` instead of `print`, it'll probably  **just work**.

Comment: In SSMS right click on database Tasks->Create scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a file from the server would be  a very bad idea. Ideally you'd be writing  it at the client. So... how are you executing the  SQL? If this is SSMS, just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. If you are using `sqlcmd`, then the `-o {filename}` switch should work. If you're executing it via ADO.NET, then `File.WriteAllText`.  Otherwise, you'll have to tell us what client tool you are using.

Note: I expect that the main problem you're seeing is that `print` is often ignored. You might prefer `select`, which *all* tools will respect.

Comment: Right the main problem was because of the print ..

Thanks for your help